# Better way of comparing integers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I wrote this class which is comparing some values, how can I improve its performance and maybe make it prettier?

You can see at the bottom what type of data it requires, also the array size can reach 100 000 elements.

As it is the class is working fine, but I would like to get a second opinion on how to improve it (I know that is not something complicated but I would like to find new ways of doing this).

```
module Stat
  class CompareData
    def initialize(datas)
      @datas = datas
      @result_data = {'g_yesterday' => {inc: 0, dec: 0}, 'g_week' => {inc: 0, dec: 0}, 'g_month' => {inc: 0, dec: 0}}
end

  def get_data
    @datas.each do |data|
      %w[g_yesterday g_week g_month].each do |compare|
        @today_value = data.g_current
        compare_data data[compare], compare
      end
    end
    @result_data
  end

  private
  def compare_data second_value, date
    unless @today_value == 0 && second_value == 0
      if @today_value != second_value
        period = @result_data[date]
        period[:dec] += 1 if @today_value == 0
        if second_value == 0
          period[:inc] += 1
        else
          @today_value < second_value ? period[:inc] += 1 : period[:dec] += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
 end
end

values = [{'g_current' => '2', 'g_yesterday' => '0', 'g_week' => '3', 'g_month' => '4'}, ..]

init = Stat::CompareData.new(values)
init.get_data
```

EDIT

I have pasted the wrong code here is the one that I wanted to post:

```
  def get_data
    @datas.each do |data|
      %w[g_yesterday g_week g_month].each do |compare|
        @today_value = data['g_current'].to_i
        compare_data data[compare].to_i, compare
      end
    end
    @result_data
  end

  def compare_data second_value, date
    unless @today_value == 0 && second_value == 0
      if @today_value != second_value
        period = @result_data[date]
        if @today_value == 0 || second_value == 0
          @today_value > second_value ? period[:inc] += 1 : period[:dec] += 1
        else
          @today_value > second_value ? period[:dec] += 1 : period[:inc] += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Minor thing: "data" is plural (the singular form is "datum"), so writing "datas" is like writing "objectses"

Comment: And also your code is broken (there's no such thing as `data.g_current`; I think you mean `data['g_current']`).

Comment: Actually, this code is so broken, it somehow ends up kinda' working. Many of your conditions are wrong since your input data uses string values, but you're comparing against integers. So something like `@today_value == 0` will _always_ be false; a string can't equal the number zero...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not usually harsh, but this code is a buggy mess. Sorry.

We don't review broken code on CodeReview, but I just can't help myself. As I said in a comment, this code is so broken that it actually ends up *almost* working correctly.

Well, except for the fact that `data.g_current` raises an exception, because you should be writing `data['g_current']`.

But let's ignore that and look at `#compare_data`:

```
def compare_data second_value, date
  # this is *always* false, since neither value is a number;
  # they're strings and a string can't be zero
  unless @today_value == 0 && second_value == 0

    # And this condition makes the one above completely redundant anyway
    if @today_value != second_value
      period = @result_data[date]

      # This *never* happens because (again) a string can't be zero.
      # But that's a good thing, because if it worked, and
      # @today_value was zero, while second_value was 1 or more
      # you'd end up adding 1 to :dec here, *and* adding 1 to
      # :inc in the else-block below
      period[:dec] += 1 if @today_value == 0

      if second_value == 0
        # this never happens either (same reason again)
        period[:inc] += 1
      else

        # this is the only line that'll ever actually do anything!
        # ... but it's broken.
        # You're comparing strings, not numbers, so in string terms,
        # "2" is greater than "10", "323" is less than "5" and so on,
        # and the branch will do the wrong thing. It just happens to
        # work if both values are single digit strings
        @today_value < second_value ? period[:inc] += 1 : period[:dec] += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In other words: there are issues here.

Other stuff:

1. What you want is a method, not a class. What you seem to be going for is a straight folding/reduction of a data set (i.e. `Array#inject`).
2. You're setting an instance variable in a loop (`@today_value`), and relying on that in a method. This is, frankly, terrible. If anything, just pass it to the method as an argument. There's just a lot of really weird coupling and state-keeping going on, none of which should be happening.
3. `#get_data` should be idempotent. Right now, if you call it more than once, you'll just get larger and larger inc/dec values because you keep adding to the same `@result_data` hash. But again, you don't want a class anyway.
4. And `#get_data` is stranger still. You set `@today_value` again and again although it doesn't change in the inner `each` loop.
5. Fix your indentation
6. Don't call a class `CompareData`. Classes should be nouns; "compare data" is imperative. And don't call a variable `init`, and don't pluralize `data` since it's already plural.
7. Be consistent with your parentheses. You use them for `#initialize`, but you don't for `#compare_data`

Here's something that I think is closer to what you're actually trying to do

```
changes = values.inject({'g_yesterday' => {inc: 0, dec: 0}, 'g_week' => {inc: 0, dec: 0}, 'g_month' => {inc: 0, dec: 0}}) do |memo, datum|
  current = datum['g_current'].to_i
  memo.each do |key, hash|
    previous = datum[key].to_i
    if current < previous
      hash[:inc] += 1
    elsif current > previous
      hash[:dec] += 1
    end
  end
  memo
end
```

No class, no strange coupling or state-keeping. Just input and output.

---

Update: New code posted, and while my answer was already accepted, I might as well. The new code is thankfully working with numbers rather than strings, which helps, but most of my points above still stand. Looking at the `#compare_data` method again:

```
def compare_data second_value, date
  # just return if you don't want to run the rest of the code
  unless @today_value == 0 && second_value == 0

    # again: This condition makes the one above pointless
    # and again, just return instead of wrapping everything
    if @today_value != second_value
      period = @result_data[date]

      # Why are zeros treated differently? Isn't the point simply to figure
      # out what value is higher, and update inc/dec accordingly?
      # Why does one of the values being zero make it behave exactly
      # opposite of how it behaves if both values are non-zero?
      #
      #  today_value   |  second_value   |  Add 1 to...
      # ----------------------------------------------
      #  1  (highest)  |  0              |  :inc
      #  2  (highest)  |  1              |  :dec
      #
      # This doesn't make sense to me... 
      if @today_value == 0 || second_value == 0
        @today_value > second_value ? period[:inc] += 1 : period[:dec] += 1
      else
        @today_value > second_value ? period[:dec] += 1 : period[:inc] += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code, the working one is a  bit similar, but is working fine. I will updated it tomorrow. Any many thanks for the help.

Comment: I've updated my code, sorry for that.

Comment: @alex Again, not to be harsh, but please either undo the update, or add the new code separately from the original code. If the code in a question changes a lot, answers (such as mine) lose their context. For instance, my answer is talking about a `compare_data` method that looks very different from the one that's now in the question, so my answer suddenly makes less sense.

Comment: @alex Thanks for updating the question to keep the original code intact. I've added a bit to my answer

Comment: Excellent answer.  You obviously put a lot of time and thought into this, and overcame obvious frustration.

Comment: About the 0. 0 means in my case, that there is no value, so that is why is treated differently. And thank you so much for your time and patience.